Why some transaction need tracing to be possible to saw them?
Native ETH transfers, unlike ERC20 or wrapped ETH (WETH) transactions, often need specialized tracing methods to be fully visible in transaction. This raises the question: why does tracing become necessary for viewing these transactions?

Because there is a difference between ETH and token transfers. ERC20 / ERC721 tokens log a Transfer event, (docs here), while native ETH transfers, do not generate an event log. For transactions that occur within smart contracts or are triggered by another contract call, they are not directly visible. For that, tracing is required if you want to check what transfers occur internally. Also, if you have more complex call structures, f.e. when a tx might lead to multiple contract calls (contract functions call other contracts), you need tracing to see the movements of ETH.
Read more about tracing here.
